# How do I POST data from React.js app to AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to send some data from my React app to an AWS Lambda through API Gateway. This is my current React code:

```js
const exampleObj = { firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Person' };

fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_PUSH_API_ENDPOINT, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT','
  mode: 'cors',
  body: JSON.stringify(exampleObj),
})
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

I keep getting an error of `Internal Server Error`. When I try to add a header of `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'`, I get an error of `Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`. I understand that the message is arising because of CORS, but I've tried several different ways, including adding a Proxy. My AWS Lambda code looks like this:

```py
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    name = event['firstName']
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : True
        },
    "body": json.dumps({
        "name": name
    })
}
```

I found that this issue arises when I try to get the POST data from event in the Lambda. I'm at loss for what to do, and help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I use Create-React-App to create my React app and I used Firefox to test. However, due to CORS errors and Firefox not letting http://localhost:3000 access https links, I tested on Chrome, only to get the same error.

EDIT 2: I figured it out! I was able to log to CloudWatch (thank you to those in the comments that helped me) and I realized that I had to "unstringify" the body when it came into the AWS Lambda using `postData = json.loads(event['body'])`. The rest of the code stayed the same.

If someone could close this question/mark it as resolved, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Anything in Cloudwatch that you can share with us? Usually, if you get `Internal Server Error`, you can find more information in Cloudwatch.

Comment: Internal Server Errors are usually bugs within the Lambda function and indicate that the request is getting in at least and is not blocked by CORS. Check if "firstName" is available in the event as you have it. You may have to dig a little deeper, something like event['body']['fileName']. It can be different for testing in the console and internet queries

Comment: @Jens I'm currently in free tier so I don't have Cloudwatch monitoring enabled.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh Still the same error when using ['body']['firstName']

Comment: @AryanIndarapu there is a free tier for CloudWatch Logs. You are just guessing, and soliciting random guesses on here, until you get the logs of the actual server-side error.

Comment: Mark B is correct the cloudwatch logs will help you. You can type print(event) above where you define name and it will print the event structure in CloudWatch and you should be able to see how to reach the 'firstName' if it is there, and if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your Lambda function try loads on the event first:

```
def handler(event, context):
  incoming_body = json.loads(event['body'])
  firstname= incoming_body['firstname']

  return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'headers': {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
      },
      'body': json.dumps(firstname)
```